# How to Use Progress bar to show iphone application loading?

Tags: iphone, progress-bar

Before app Loads The Default.png is shown fine till here next is to show Progress bar.
And then it will show the application view.
Please Supply code example ?
Hope you got it all :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first place you can start drawing is in your applicationDelegate, in appDidFinishLoading.  You might want to put up a progress bar there, maybe on a UIImageView that uses your Default.png.  You can also create a Timer task in order to add a little to your progress bar, either on every second, or millisecond, or you could have a counter that you are incrementing as you are initializing various pieces of your code, and the timer task can use that counter to update the progress bar.  Just before you show the final application view then draw the final part of the progress bar and wait a split second for the user to see it.

Comment: Sounds Difficult... Any examples ?

Comment: No examples, I know of.  Look around for iphone+"progress bar".  What part do you find difficult and I'll try to give you some pointers.  The drawing of a progress bar could be as simple as using 5 or so images of a progress bar at different values.  Or you can use the UIProgressView.