# how to add initloader in iphone

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone.i have done a small application but what i need is when i click the application icon it shows just like process bar going on and opens the application how can i done this pls help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use Progress bar to show iphone application loading ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492287/how-to-use-progress-bar-to-show-iphone-application-loading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load a screen on didFinishLaunch that screen is generally called splash screen do the animation in it and at the end switch to your first screen. here are some examples

[ref 1](http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/03/creating-a-splash-screen-part-one.html)
[ref 2](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/)